# android, NumberPicker Out of bounds

Tags: android, numberpicker

```
NumberPicker serviceWheel = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.serviceSelector);
serviceWheel.setMaxValue(serviceArray.length());
String[] profiles = new String[serviceArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < serviceArray.length(); i++){
   JSONObject profileObject = serviceArray.getJSONObject(i);
   profiles[i] = profileObject.getString("description");
}
serviceWheel.setDisplayedValues(profiles);
serviceWheel.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
            at android.widget.NumberPicker.ensureCachedScrollSelectorValue(NumberPicker.java:1756)
            at android.widget.NumberPicker.incrementSelectorIndices(NumberPicker.java:1722)
            at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1097)
            at android.widget.NumberPicker.onTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:880)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7565)
```

`serviceArray` is a `JSONArray`, with a length of `3`. I tried to add padding when instatiating the array ( `serviceArray.length() + 1` ) but this caused failure before the activity was shown. The NumberPicker displays fine but when i scroll to the last entry of the array, it crashes with this error. There is no reference to code line in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from this:

```
serviceWheel.setMaxValue(serviceArray.length());
```

to this:

```
serviceWheel.setMaxValue(serviceArray.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

This means you are trying to get the element of index 3 in something of length 3.

**Remember that in computer science, we start counting from 0**.

*See comments for edited solution (initial was wrong).*

Comment: your answer is correct, but the solution doesn't make any sense. if the length of the jsonarray is 3, setting the max value of the number picker to 2 would surely omit the final array index. i understand that we count from 0 inclusive, its why i attempted padding etc. that isn't the issue. 

do i assume that i always set NumberPicker MaxValue to one less than the actual number of elements/numbers to display?? What if i had an array of length 1. the max value will be 0, surely not displaying anything

Comment: You're right. Should should `setMaxValue(serviceArray.length())` but use it's `value - 1` to retrieve the "real" value.